# How hard is it to replace a hollow-core door with a solid one?

Tags: door

The pantry door in my kitchen is a hollow-core door. There's quite a lot of wasted space between the door and the existing shelves, that I'd like to utilize by hanging full-width, full-height, 8"-10' shelves on the inside surface of the door.

The plans I've worked up suggest that the shelves, when full, would be supporting quite a bit of weight, and I'm concerned that the hollow-core door won't be able to support it adequately.

How difficult is it to replace one door with another using the existing frame/jams, etc. It seems pretty straight-forward, but something tells me that there's more to it than I imagine...

Is this something that is worth doing, or is it a rabbit-hole of pain and disappointment?

Comment: Could you re-phrase the Question? As-asked it's too open-ended for SE (the Answer basically boiling down to: it depends on you). Do your due diligence, then come back with a specific Question asking for clarification or tips on any aspect that you need help with *if any*.

Comment: Maybe better for DIY https://diy.stackexchange.com/. Howver, we don't know the size of the door, whether the existing door is any sort of standard pre-hung door, etc. You may also consider that there are fasteners that can hold a fair amount of mass installed in a hollow space. You could use these to mount 2-3 wood or metal vertical supports that shelves would themselves fasten to. Alternatively, mount the shelves across the jambs -- if these shelves are as heavy as you say you probably don't want them swinging out on the door anyway.

Comment: If you do want to allow for movement, consider how the shelves will interfere with the full movement of the door. Good luck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more for DIY than anything

Comment: I agree this would be more on-topic on DIY.  Is it possible to migrate questions with answers?  (If not, I can delete the answer, and then recreate it once migrated.)

Comment: Amazon, et al, have lots of hits for "hollow door fasteners" BTW. If you want to go this route, don't bother with replacing the door. Design rails that fasten to the door and provide a level and secure point for adjustable shelves.

Comment: I agree... this is the wrong place for this question. I recreated it in DIY...but can't delete it here because it has an answer... Thanks, all, for the constructive comments and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've replaced about half-a-dozen doors over time.  The old ones were mostly very tatty, old, solid-wood doors (rather than hollow-core), but that doesn't matter.

The important point is that the *new* doors are solid wood.  This is because the new doors need to fit (exactly) the existing door-frames ... and it is a lot easier to cut 10mm off the side of a solid door than it is with a hollow-core.  Obviously measure the door frame carefully (and if you have an old house, don't assume it is rectangular!)

Replacing the doors themselves is relatively straightforward.  The thing I would be more worried about, is the jams: can they take the load?  You might also want to consider having more and bigger hinges to take the load - but you'll probably want new hinges anyway.

I'd go for it!

Comment: Is the right answer, *for you*. But I can't support it as an Answer to the Question as posed. Take for example the non-square opening that you mention, which is the classic problem faced when fitting a new door to an existing frame (and not just in old houses LOL)..... we don't know whether the OP is one of those people for whom changing their rectilinear door to a parallelogram or other non-square shape is an insurmountable problem as it is for some people, either because of practical (don't have the required tools) or conceptual (can't visualise the correct course of action) limitations.

Comment: @Graphus: This is about the kind of answer I was looking for. Along with the comments, I should be able to move forward. +2 points for "rectilinear".